# NodeJS addon can just be executed with self compiled nodeJS

Tags: c++, node.js, add-on

I tried some work on compiling some C++/CLI NodeJS addons.
For example, I wanted to read from Windows Event logs.

At first, I compiled nodeJS to get the node.lib file. Basicly, I followed the steps mentioned in this document: http://coderesearchlabs.com/articles/BNWCA.pdf

I set up an VisualStudio Project with include and library paths pointing to the compiled node 0.10.28 directories.
In this project I made use of the System::Diagnostics::EventLog class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.eventlog

After finishing my C++ project, I compiled it successfully and could use it with the node.exe from the first step.

Now, I tried to use my "EventReader.node" file on an other machine. But I couldn't require the node file:

```
Error: no error
```

This is the error I got after requiring the node-file.

Some hints:
Both machines run Windows 7 Professional
NodeJS version I self compiled: 0.10.28 src
NodeJS version I tried to run my addon with: 0.10.28 msi

Edit:
After using node-gyp, I need to set my references in the vxproj-file. In special these ones:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
</ItemGroup>
```

But how do I add these with the gyp-file?

Comment: Do you use node-gyp for compiling?

Comment: I compiled it with VisualStudio. How do I compile it with node-gyp and DLL references?

Comment: You should take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21611867/how-to-build-a-native-node-js-extension-using-node-gyp-on-win-7-x64-vs2012 and https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp

Comment: Okay thanks. I tried it with node-gyp, but there is still an answer missing. I edited it above.